Find all files in directory and apply commands to each of them
I want to apply commands below to all files in a directory instead of one file.
cat file.txt | sed -E "s/\@([0-9]+)\W+~(.*?)/\1 \2/g" | tr -d '~'

cat file.txt | sed -E "s/\@([0-9]+).*\~(.*)[~\r\n]/\1 \2/g" | sed -E "s/([0-9]+)\W+(.*)/\@\1\ = ~\2~/g"


Edit the question and include what is supposed to be done to the files including sample text from some of the files and the expected output. Also, include where what you have isn't working.

supplemental to @NasirRiley feedback: "find  -maxdepth 1 -type f"  will return a list of non directories) , will not traverse subdirectories. put that in a loop to your sed commands , which needs modifying to make changes permanent to files being processed ( you'll need to add the -i flag to your commands ), all that said, i highly recommend you 1: read the sed manpage documentation carefully. 2: do this with a set of test files in a sandbox area away from any production/important actual data and be 100% sure your commands do what you expect them to .

Do you need the resulting output to be: for each file, "file content modified by command1" followed by "file content modified by command2"?

Are you familiar with the command xargs? Together with find it can do a lot of things like this. (In most cases you can do it with find's exec instead of xargs- but the syntax is more awkward. IMHO)

With zsh instead of bash:
for file in some/dir/*(ND-.); do
  sed -Ee 's/@([0-9]+)\W+~/\1 /g; s/~//g' -- $file &&
    sed -Ee 's/@([0-9]+).*~(.*)[~\r]/\1 \2/g
             s/([0-9]+)\W+(.*)/@\1\ = ~\2~/g' -- $file
done

Where ND-. is to restrict to files of type regular (determined after symlink resolution with -) and including Dot-files (hidden files).
I've removed a few backslashes that were not only not needed but potentially not future proof as you might find that \@ or \~ have a special meaning in future versions of sed, \n which doesn't make sense as sed works on the contents of lines which doesn't include line delimiters.
I've also removed the (.*?) which, in sed implementations that recognise that perl operator (which are few) would be pointless as it would match only the empty string.
Beyond that, I can't comment further as to whether those substitutions make sense as you've not specified what they're meant to do.
In bash, it's possible but more cumbersome:
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
for file in some/dir/*; do
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue
  sed -Ee 's/@([0-9]+)\W+~/\1 /g; s/~//g' -- "$file" &&
    sed -Ee 's/@([0-9]+).*~(.*)[~\r]/\1 \2/g
             s/([0-9]+)\W+(.*)/@\1\ = ~\2~/g' -- "$file"
done

['s -f also checks the type of files after symlink resolution, change to [ -f "$file" ] && [ ! -L "$file" ] to exclude symlinks.
With the GNU implementation of find, you can also do:
find -H some/dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -xtype f \
  -exec sed -Ee 's/@([0-9]+)\W+~/\1 /g; s/~//g' -- {} ';' \
  -exec sed -Ee 's/@([0-9]+).*~(.*)[~\r]/\1 \2/g
                 s/([0-9]+)\W+(.*)/@\1\ = ~\2~/g' -- {} ';'

But beware the list of files is not sorted so you'll get them in seemingly random order. Omitting hidden files (the equivalent of removing D or dotglob above) would also need a ! -name '.*', which to be reliable would have to be done in the C locale, which would affect sed's matching, so you'd need something like:
LC_ALL=C find -H some/dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -xtype f \
  -exec env -u LC_ALL sed -Ee 's/@([0-9]+)\W+~/\1 /g; s/~//g' -- {} ';' \
  -exec env -u LC_ALL sed -Ee 's/@([0-9]+).*~(.*)[~\r]/\1 \2/g
                               s/([0-9]+)\W+(.*)/@\1\ = ~\2~/g' -- {} ';'

(which assumes LC_ALL was otherwise not initially set), where we set the locale to C for find, but revert it for sed.

Those are doing the job, seeing on console but those aren't changing the files themselves. Only outputting the desired result to screen not to the actual files.
